# slide show img shrink in wordpress theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, width

I just got this theme and tried to import background image like the recommended size in the documentation but It seems something is odd 
and these images have CSS problems in theme style.css

here is the link of my website
http://test.doublelift.kr

and here is the demonstration of the actual template

http://www.cssvillain.com/hungry/

the problem is abovious if you resize the window and see the image file shrink slowly instead of changing width based on px.

The image width is based on percentage on the template I've got, so I tried to make it to auto and write the style based on the height just like the original template
but It seems It is reading the style from somewhere else 
no success on chrome's developer tool

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#single-page-header {
    height: 1000px !important;
    overflow-y: visible !important;
}

.cycle-slideshow {
    position: relative !important;
}

#single-pager-header .cycle-slideshow img {
    display: block !important;
    max-height: 1000px !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1370px) and (min-width: 1025px) {
    #single-page-header {
        height: 720px !important;
    }

    #single-page-header .cycle-slideshow img {
        max-height: 720px !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .single-page-header-content {
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }

    .single-page-header-content .cycle-slide-show {
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    #single-page-header .cycle-slideshow img {
        max-height: 1000px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #single-page-header {
        height: 500px !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    #single-page-header .cycle-slideshow img {
        max-height: 1000px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change the revolution slider setting for specific screen sizes options over there and then change the css according to your requirements.
This is the best way to handle i see.